# Discord.py Listening for a Message after a Command

Tags: python, discord.py

I've been trying to create a bot command that listens for a message after the command is sent. This is meant to be used to create a profile of the command author to later store in a JSON file.

```py
@client.command()     #creates player profile
async def create(ctx):
    await ctx.send("You will be asked a series of questions to create your Profile. If you accidentally typed this wait 15 seconds for it to cancel.")
    message = await client.wait_for('message',check=None,timeout=15)
    await ctx.send(message) #used to check what message is holding
```

While the code above works, it doesn't work as I want it to. It sends back the id's of the server, member, channel, message, and the author, along with other information, instead of holding the reply by the command author.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, what you want is to store the user's input data and append them as like an interview form:

It takes the user's input messages and appends them to the message they answered like:

```py
q_list = [
    'Your question 1',
    'Your question 2',
    'Your question 3']

a_list = []


@client.command()
async def create(ctx):

        await ctx.send("You will be asked a series of questions to create your Profile. If you accidentally typed this wait 15 seconds for it to cancel.")

        a_list = []
        submit_channel = client.get_channel(CHANNEL_ID_FOR_SUBMISSIONS)
        channel = await ctx.author.create_dm()

        def check(m):
                return m.content is not None and m.channel == channel

        for question in q_list:
                await asyncio.sleep(3)
                await channel.send(question)
                msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)
                a_list.append(msg.content)

        submit_wait = True
        while submit_wait:
                await channel.send(
                    'You have completed the interview, type ``submit`` to confirm')
                msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)
                if "submit" in msg.content.lower():
                        submit_wait = False
                        answers = "\n".join(f'{a}. {b}' for a, b in enumerate(a_list, 1))
                        submit_msg = f'''**Submission - Created by {msg.author.mention}** \n{answers}'''
                        await submit_channel.send(submit_msg)
```