# How to exit a while loop under the decorator command in discord?

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to command my bot on stopping the loop whenever the user will type 'stop'. What code do you think I must write?

```
@bot.command()
async def loop(ctx):
   while True:
      await ctx.send('It\'s Looping!')
#.......?
```

I'm new in this field that's y, Thanks : )

Comment: Check [Discord.py Listening for a Message after a Command](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65728788/10824407).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord.py Make bot wait for reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62965226/discord-py-make-bot-wait-for-reply)

Answer (score 1):

You can either store whether the loop should be running in a variable, like so:

```py
should_loop = False

@bot.command()
async def loop(ctx):
    global should_loop
    should_loop = True
    while should_loop:
        await ctx.send("It's Looping!")

@bot.command()
async def stop(ctx):
    global should_loop
    should_loop = False
```

which works fine if you're only ever expecting one loop to be active at any time.

Alternatively, and what works better in my opinion, you can use the `bot.wait_for` coroutine:

```py
@bot.command()
async def loop(ctx):
    should_loop = True

    async def looper():
        while should_loop:
            await ctx.send("It's Looping!")

    async def listener():
        nonlocal should_loop
        try:
            await bot.wait_for("message", check=lambda m: m.content == "stop", timeout=60)
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            pass
        else:
            should_loop = False

    await asyncio.gather(looper(), listener())
```

This second approach allows you to have a separate `should_loop` for each loop command call, which could be what you want.